# Bind button command to source other than parent's datacontext

Tags: silverlight, xaml, mvvm-light

I am trying to bind the command of a button inside a datacontext to a RelayCommand in the Main viewmodel.  When I use Blend it changes the datacontext of the containing grid to point to the Main ViewModel thus breaking the binding of the content of the grid which should be based on the viewmodel of the row etc.  I tried the following but the compiler says I am missing an attribute name.

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource StatusButtonStyle}">
                    <Button.Command>
                        <Binding Source="{StaticResource Locator" Path="{Main.ViewStatusCommand}" Mode="OneWay"                 
                    </Button.Command>
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </Button>
```

I also tried this:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource StatusButtonStyle}" Command="{Binding Main.ViewStatusCommand, Source=StaticResource Locator}">
```

But that doesn't work either.  If I am not alowed to set the source of the command binding, could someone please explain why?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot some brackets in the second exemple (and the first lack a /> in the Binding element )

```
<Button Style={StaticResource StatusButtonStyle}" Command="{Binding Main.ViewStatusCommand, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
```

Is it the reason explaining why it don't work? If it's not the case, could you please describe your symptoms (nothing happen when I push the button, there is an Exception (if this is the case, when, and what exception? ) )

If nothing happen when you push the button, look at the debugging console to retreive the Bindings errors.

Comment: That did it.  Thank you!  I feel really stupid now.  Can you explain why sometimes you need the brackets and sometimes you do?  Or at least point me in the right direction.  My second attempt did not throw any errors and I know that by itself there would be brackets around staticResource but not nested like that.